# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'path') Firebase ref function conflict

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

**Error:**

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'path')

according to my testing,

```
   import { getStorage, ref, uploadBytesResumable, getDownloadURL } 
    from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.1/firebase-storage.js";
    
    import { getDatabase, set, child, get, update, remove } 
    from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.1/firebase-database.js";
    
    const realdb = getDatabase();
```

the error is becuase *ref( )* function from **firebase-storage** is different from *ref( )* from **firebase-database**

but i can import only one of the function, so what to do?
to save the downloadURL i need both (firebase-storage) and (firebase-database).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just rename one of the imports like this:

```
import { getStorage, ref as storageRef } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.1/firebase-storage.js";
```

Then make sure you used `storageRef()` instead of `ref()` for storage in your code.

Comment: thanks you so much, i didn't know it was so easy the error is resolved, my hunch was correct ref functions from both liabraries were conflicting.

Comment: @HassaanRaza If you ever use deconstruction assignments, you can also rename the exported properties like so: `const { getStorage, ref: storageRef } = firebaseStorageExports;` (don't actually use a `firebaseStorageExports` object, just used here as an example to match above)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are imported and initialized the app before use some storage functions.

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";


initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```